# KVM idle VM CPU 100% usage with ehci

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, kvm

My idle KVM Windows VM used 100% CPU.
It went from 100% host CPU down to 3% host CPU after I disabled ehci(Standard Enhanced PCI to USB Host Controller) in Device Manager.
Device Magener Picture
[image]

Vm run normally at the beginning. It went up to 100% after a long timer(may be one night long).

1. Why the cpu usage reduced when I disabled the ehci?
2. Is there any other way to reduce the cpu usage?

Here is my libvirt.xml

```
<domain type="kvm" xmlns:qemu="http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0">
  <name>i-win2003/name>
  <os>
    <type>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <clock offset="localtime"/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <vcpu current="1">1</vcpu>
 <memory>2097152</memory>
  <currentMemory>2097152</currentMemory>
  <devices>
    <disk device="disk" type="file">
      <driver name="qemu" type="qcow2"/>
      <source file="/root/i-win2003/snap.qcow2"/>
      <target bus="virtio" dev="vda"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <source dev=''/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
    </disk>
    <serial type="pty">
      <source path="/dev/pts/1"/>
      <target port="0"/>
    </serial>
   <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='fa:16:3e:81:68:b4'/>
      <source bridge='eucabr'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
    </interface>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
    </channel>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-ehci1"/>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci1"/>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci2"/>
    <controller type="usb" index="0" model="ich9-uhci3"/>
    <input type="tablet" bus="usb"/>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="vnc" port="-1" autoport="yes" keymap="en-us" listen="0.0.0.0"/>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

Comment: Maybe using the 'tablet' resulted in many contex switches?